# How to select all child from document.queryselectorall() over eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, queryselector

```
const modalTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger");
modalTriggers.forEach((modalTrigger) => {
    modalTrigger.addEventListener("click", (clickEvent) => {
        const trigger = clickEvent.target;
        const modalId = trigger.getAttribute("data-modal-id");
        openModal(modalId);
    });
});
```

```
<button class="modal-trigger bg-brandPrimary-500 rounded-full p-8 shadow-custom text-white" data-modal-id="openFilterDialog"><span><i data-feather="layers" ></i></span></button>
```

When I click over the #span #i it won't trigger the data-modal-id but when I click over the #button it triggers the data-modal-id. What is the possible way to trigger data-modal-id if we click over either button span or I? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: click over? i guess you mean just clicking on those elements?

Comment: @RamondeVries The OP probably means 'clicking while the mouse is over element', which is the same as clicking on the element.

Comment: yes although they are a child of .modal-trigger they won't accept the parent class that have been selected? I want the trigger to happen when I click either the parent or those child elements

Answer (score 0):

Just use your already existing modalTrigger variable instead of looking at the target.

```
const modalTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger");
modalTriggers.forEach((modalTrigger) => {
    modalTrigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const modalId = modalTrigger.getAttribute("data-modal-id");
        openModal(modalId);
    });
});
```

Another solution is to disable the click events on the child elements with CSS [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

```
.modal-trigger * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure the `.parent()` will select the right element when clicked on the `i` but the `.children()` onclick is the correct thing to detect the right click event on the child elements

```js
$(".modal-trigger").children().on('click', function(){
$(this).parent().click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="modal-trigger bg-brandPrimary-500 rounded-full p-8 shadow-custom text-white" data-modal-id="openFilterDialog"><span>dddd<i data-feather="layers" ></i></span></button>
```